# Cannot boot into any OS any more after bcdedit

Tags: windows, windows-10, multi-boot, mbr

I have a dual boot on my Dell laptop, Windows 10 and Kali Linux. During the weekend I did not boot into Kali since I use it just for work. I stayed on Windows because of gaming. There have been a massive update and I did it, then today (Monday) when I tried to boot into Kali I found that I couldn't.

I knew sometimes Windows update could mess up dual boot installations, so I didn't panic and I figured out that the problem could have been Grub. After some research I found that I could fix that with just a couple of commands (spoiler: it made things worse) so I typed in the following, thinking it would bring back the possibility to boot back into Kali:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\kali\grubx64.efi
```

Then I restarted the pc to finally boot into Kali and I wasn't still able to do it. So I figured out I would just reinstall it, since i had already got my important stuff back, but I couldn't even get into windows.
So I did other research on the web but none of the things I found worked out for me (bcdedit /export from a live usb, bootrec /fixmbr and bootrec /fixboot which gives me access denied, while /export gives me that the requested system device cannot be found).

I can perform a clean install because my important stuff is already backed up on the cloud or other hard drives, but I would lose around 300+ GB of videogames and personal data that I prefer  to keep.

My settings when booting are the following: UEFI and SECURE BOOT OFF.

Comment: Two suggestions: 1. Edit the .efi bootloaders manually. See https://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html  2. Image the whole disk, reinstall Windows and Linux, the restore the partitions with data and games.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik actually imaging the whole disk would take more time than performing a fresh install and re-downloading everything, even if it would be the best option not to lose anything. If i manage to edit the bootloader files manually I'll give it a shot tomorrow, otherwise I think I will just go for a clean install.